# Flask: Prevent HTML escaping in the browser's URL bar

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a RESTful API in Flask. It allows wildcards to be used. The problem is that when a URL is entered, such as `mysite.com/get/abc*`, Flask turns this URL into `mysite.com/get/abc%2A`, both on the backend and in the browser's URL bar.

This is easy enough to handle on the backend, but how can I prevent the browser's URL bar from containing ugly things like '%2A'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not Flask that turns `*` into `%2A`, it is the browser.

Character `*` is not legal in an URL and there is nothing you can do about it. Browsers must escape illegal characters in sent requests. A browser might leave `*` in the address bar (and escape it silently), but you should not expect browsers to do so.

Comment: If I put a * in the URL bar on StackOverflow, it keeps it as a *. I'm okay with it escaping it in the request, I'm just worried about user-friendliness. I don't want someone to see a %2A and get confused.

Comment: I wrote a tiny Flask app, opened it in my browser with a `*` and it was not escaped too, but that is not the point. The point is that it is a bad idea to rely on this behaviour.

Comment: Figured out why * was changing to %2A. It does a 301 redirect if you enter a URL without a closing `/`. This 301 causes the browser to switch the * to %2A. `mysite.com/*` becomes `mysite.com/%2A/`. I turned off strict_slashes, but I'll leave my handlers for %2A's and stuff in the Flask app, in case another browser behaves differently.